# How to raise an error, if the parsed number of a C++ stdlib stream is immediately followed by a non whitespace character?

Tags: c++, stream

In the following example, I didn't expect, that `1.2345foo` would be parsed. Since I am reading data files, it is probably better to raise an error and notify the user.

Is `peek()` the correct thing to do here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
  std::stringstream in("1.2345foo");

  double x;

  in >> x;

  if (in) {
    std::cout << "good\n";
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "bad\n";
  }
}
```

Output

```
good
```

Comment: Are you comfortable using a regex?

Comment: I think that if you have requirements that are more complex than the basic formatting offered by iostreams then you should analyse your data character by character. Write a parser in other words.

Comment: @jpumford I am still on C++03.

Comment: Using `peek` may be the correct solution.  Your title and your text seem to ask slightly different questions.

Comment: @john Or use regular expressions, or something.  I agree, _if_ the requirements are more complex than the basic formatting offered by `std::istream`.  In this case, I don't think they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look-ahead at the next character.  In the case of an
isolated `std::istringstream`, you can do something like:

```
if ( in >> x && in.get() == std::string::traits_type::eof() ) {
    //  good
} else {
    //  bad
}
```

(I generally like to separate the tests, in order to give more
meaningfull error messages.)

If you're concerned with data in a larger file, where for
example `"1.2345 foo"` would be legal, but `"1.2345foo"` not,
you can use look-ahead, something like:

```
if ( in >> x 
        && (std::isspace( in.peek() )
            || in.peek() == std::string::traits_type::eof())  ) {
    //  good
} else {
    //  bad
}
```

EDIT:

I forgot to mention: in the first case, you might want to skip
white space before checking for eof:

```
if ( in >> x >> std::ws && in.get() == std::string::traits_type::eof() ) ...
```

(I do this a lot.  If the string input is from `std::getline`,
you really do want to allow trailing white space, since it is
invisible for anyone looking at the file.)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to read it as `std::string`, and then use [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) to convert the `std::string` into `double`. The conversion function will throw exception for invalid input such as when you pass `"1.2345foo"` to it.